# How to run Tiller on Kubernetes cluster on AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I created EKS Kubernetes cluster with terraform. It all went fine, cluster is created and there is one EC2 machine on it. However, I can't init helm and install Tiller there. All the code is on https://github.com/amorfis/aws-eks-terraform

As stated in README.md, after cluster creation I update `~/.kube/config`, create rbac, and try to init helm. However, it's pod is still pending:

```
$> kubectl --namespace kube-system get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-7554568866-8mnsm         0/1     Pending   0          3h
coredns-7554568866-mng65         0/1     Pending   0          3h
tiller-deploy-77c96688d7-87rb8   0/1     Pending   0          1h
```

As well as other 2 `coredns` pods.

What am i missing?

UPDATE: Output of `describe`:

```
$> kubectl describe pod tiller-deploy-77c96688d7-87rb8 --namespace kube-system
Name:               tiller-deploy-77c96688d7-87rb8
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               <none>
Labels:             app=helm
                    name=tiller
                    pod-template-hash=3375224483
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/tiller-deploy-77c96688d7
Containers:
  tiller:
    Image:       gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.12.2
    Ports:       44134/TCP, 44135/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Liveness:    http-get http://:44135/liveness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:   http-get http://:44135/readiness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      TILLER_NAMESPACE:    kube-system
      TILLER_HISTORY_MAX:  0
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from tiller-token-b9x6d (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  tiller-token-b9x6d:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  tiller-token-b9x6d
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: Hi can you run `kubectl describe pod tiller-deploy-77c96688d7-87rb8` ?

Comment: There also are no nodes, which is strange, because there is an EC2 instance created on AWS.

Comment: lol, if no nodes then it will be in pending

Comment: But why there are no nodes? And what can I do to have some?

Comment: you need to check terraform's log if there is an api call to create the nodes

Comment: Quite amusing to see that you have the tried deploying pods even before a node is up!
For EKS to discover nodes, it requires the use of the right tags and settings. 

Can you post the tags of the EC2 instance that is running please? 
Along with the following - 
EKS VPC, Subnets and Security groups. 
Something needs to be amended here afaik.

Answer (score 1):

try to allow the master to run pods
according to this issue [issue form githup](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4181)

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```